# ¿Qué significan los símbolos "&" y ">>" en Python?

Tags: python, operador

No encuentro en Internet qué significan estos símbolos en Python: `&` y `>>`.

Encontré que `&` sería intersección, pero no creo que aplique en el siguiente código que no logro entender:

```
def numberOfSteps (self, num: int) -> int:
    stepCount = 0 if num else 1
    while num:
        stepCount += (num & 1) + 1
        num >>= 1
    return stepCount - 1
```

Comment: Que fabulosa y completa respuesta!! Muchas gracias!!

Comment: si la respuesta te ayuda, es recomendable aceptarla (con un check que hay debajo de la opcion de votar)

Comment: ahhh muchas gracias Christian!! No sabia!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Operadores Bitwise

Los operadores Bitwise se utilizan para hacer operaciones entre los bits de un numero, comúnmente son llamadas operaciones bit a bit.

## Operador >> (bitwise right shift)

El operador `>>` se llama *rshift* o *right shift* el cual indica un desplazamiento a la derecha por n bits. aquí un ejemplo

```py
a = 60            #0011 1100 
b = 13            #0000 1101 

#si   hacemos a >> 2 se moverá 2 bits a la derecha
r = a >> 2
#r = 0000 1111
print(r) #15
```

En algunas partes se dice que es similar a hacer `num/pow(2,n)` lo cual no es muy correcto, púes estos operadores se usan en números enteros y una división como esa nos devolverá un decimal, hacemos un ejemplo

```py
#operador
60 >> 2
#15

#formula
60/pow(2,2)
#15

#otra vez
60 >> 3
#7

60/pow(2,3)
#7.5
```

En el ultimo caso no es lo mismo ya que no es igual desplazar los bits de un numero que dividir u operar con el. La forma correcta seria convirtiendolo a entero `int(60/pow(2,3))` ya que operamos con enteros. Otra forma seria la que dijo @tincopasan en los comentarios, con la doble barra `//` la cual devuelve la parte entera de la división `60//pow(2,3)`.

## Operador & (bitwise and)

Como dije en un principio las operaciones bitwise son de bit a bit por lo que está no tiene el mismo efecto que el operador **and** ya que este se utiliza con valores boleanos. Además la operación que realice  `&` será distinta según el tipo de dato, algo interesante de este operador es que se puede redefinir sus métodos como `__and__` y `__rand__`.

En este caso el operador hace lo mismo que haría con los conjuntos una intersección pero con los bits del numero, retornando 1 si ambos números son 1 y 0 si no lo son. Vamos a ver un ejemplo con los mismos valores

```py
a = 60            #0011 1100 
b = 13            #0000 1101

r = a & b 
#calculamos la interseccion entre 0011 1100 y 0000 1101
#0011 1100
#0000 1101
#interseccion -> 0000 1100
print(r) #12
```

Esto nos da como resultado esta cadena de bits `0000 1100` el cual representa al numero 12.

## Tu código

Lo que hace tu codigo es, que recibe un numero el cual verifica si es `True` o `False`, sera **True** cuando sea cualquier numero o cadena no vacia; **False** cuando sea 0 o una cadena vacia `""` y le asigna el valor de 0 o 1. Luego haya la intersección con 1 (en bits), ahora pasamos al ciclo `while`

```py
#supongamos que num es 7
#por lo que la condición es True asi que stepCount= 0

while num:
    stepCount += (num & 1) + 1 #aqui se haya la interseccion con 1 y luego +1
    #seria 0 += (1) +1 = 2
    num >>= 1 #aqui se correra un bit a la derecha
    #en este caso los bits representaran al 3
    #el ciclo se repetira hasta que num sea 0 bits ->0000 0000
return stepCount - 1 # se retornara el valor acumulado en la variable -1
```

Como ves tu codigo mueve una posicion de bits del numero hasta que sea `0000 0000` y retornara un valor que se ha ido acumulando

Comment: No sé si python intencionalmente llama a & diferente, pero lo que describes es una operación que en el resto de la informática se llama _and_. De hecho, es por eso mismo que en algunos lenguajes se usa el símbolo `&` para representarla, pues `&` en inglés se lee _and_.

Comment: @jachguate si, en python es diferente el operador *and* , para representar el *and* existe la palabra reservada **and** (lo mismo pasa con `|` y **or** ) , si tratas de hacer una operacion con diccionarios esto hara la operacion de interseccion, aqui te dejo un codigo que puedes probar `a = {1,2,3,5,6}
b = {3,5,9,11}
print(a&b)`

Comment: @Christian no es obligatorio usar int en: int(60/pow(2,3)) también se puede usando 60//pow(2,3) donde devolverá solo la parte entera

Comment: @tincopasan gracias, ya fue añadido a la respuesta

Comment: @jachguate @christian `&` suele llamarse "_bitwise and_" para diferenciarlo del "_boolean and_", que es el que en python se implementa en el operador `and` y otros lenguajes como C con el operador  `&&`. Análogamente `|`  es el _bitwise or_, frente al _boolean or_ que en python sería `or` y en otros lenguajes `||`. Otro detalle es que en python tanto `&` como `|` pueden variar su significado según sobre qué tipos se apliquen (enteros, conjuntos, diccionarios, dataframes pandas, o tus propias clases), mientras que `and` y `or`  no pueden ser redefinidos y siempre operan sobre booleanos.

Comment: @abulafia gracias por las aclaraciones, no había tomado en cuenta eso al momento de la explicación, la respuesta fue editada :)