# Cómo utilizar el operador << dentro de un ciclo for en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estoy iniciando en python y me he estancado en mi curso.
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
valores << 3 << 7 << 8 << 90 << 12
```

lo que trato de hacer es obtener la misma operación pero dentro de un ciclo for, algo como esto:

```
for x in xrange(1,5):
    valores << x
```

si lo hago de esa forma obtengo como resultado un error. La verdad no habia trabajado con operadores Bitwise en python hasta ahora. Si no se puede realizar lo que deseo, hay alguna otra forma de representar los datos que estan en la variable Valores?

Comment: puedes leer esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453092/qu%c3%a9-significan-los-s%c3%admbolos-y-en-python/453112#453112)

Comment: otra cosa es que es `range()` y no `xrange` eso no existe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar tu código esta bien, lo que tienes es un error de sintaxis, como no muestras la variable `valores` le voy a dar un valor.

```py
valores = 10
for x in range(1,5): #no es xrange
    valores = valores << x
    print(f"valores={valores}")
```

Esto da como resultado

```
valores=20
valores=80
valores=640
valores=10240
```

No me voy a poner a explicar el resultado, puedes encontrar mas detalles sobre los operadores bitwise en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453092/qu%c3%a9-significan-los-s%c3%admbolos-y-en-python/453112#453112)

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora si esta funcionando bien.