# Multiplicación de dos números sin usar la operación y además llevando en Java

Tags: java

No sé si está bien resumida la pregunta, pero tengo un problema que no logro solucionar

se trata de multiplicar dos números y obtener el resultado, pero sin usar la operación de multiplicar. este es el problema:

Para multiplicar un número (multiplicando) de varias cifras por otro de una cifra (multiplicador) se empieza por la cifra de las unidades del multiplicado, que se multiplica por cada una de las unidades del multiplicador, obteniéndose un resultado parcial al que se suma la llevada anterior, que la primera vez es cero. De este resultado se apuntan las unidades, pero no las decenas que pasan  a  ser  la  llevada.  Ahora  se  repite  el proceso  con el  resto de  los  dígitos  del multiplicador.

Al finalizar si hubiera llevada se lleva al resultado.

Este es el código que llevo, y funciona bien a medias, pero no del todo, a veces da resultados diferentes, sobre todo si pongo multiplicadores de dos cifras

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] numeros = metodoPedirNumeros();
    int ando = numeros[0];
    int dor = numeros[1];
    //ArraList<Integer> resultado = metodoMultiplicarLlevando(ando, dor);
    metodoMultiplicarLlevando(ando, dor);
}
public static int[] metodoPedirNumeros(){
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numeros = new int[2];
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese el multiplicando");
    numeros[0] = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el multiplicador");
    numeros[1] = teclado.nextInt();
    return numeros;
}
public static ArrayList<Integer> metodoMultiplicarLlevando(int ando, int dor){
    
    String sAndo = Integer.toString(ando);
    int nAndo = sAndo.length();
    int mul = 0;
    int resu = 0;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for (int i = nAndo; i > 0; i--){
        mul = 0;
        char n = sAndo.charAt(i - 1);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n));
        for (int j = 0; j < dor; j++){
            mul += num; 
        }  
        mul = mul + num1;
        if ((mul > 0) && (mul < 10)){
            numeros.add(mul);
        }
        if ((mul > 9) && (mul < 100)){
            String s2 = Integer.toString(mul);
            char n1 = s2.charAt(0);
            char n2 = s2.charAt(1);
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n1));
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n2));
            numeros.add(mul);
        }            
    }
    System.out.println("El resultado de multiplicar " + ando + " * " + dor + " es de: ");
    for (int k = 0; k < numeros.size(); k++){
        System.out.print(numeros.get(k));
    }
    System.out.println("");
    return numeros;
}
public static void metodoImprimirResultados(ArrayList<Integer> resultado){
    System.out.println("El resultado de multiplicar " + ando + " * " + dor + " es de: ");
    for (int k = 0; k < resultado.size(); k++){
        System.out.print(resultado.get(k));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: ¿Te serviría una respuesta con multiplicación bitwise?

Comment: Podrías agregar la respuesta, por favor ?. Desconozco ese método que mencionas y será interesante conocerlo. Gracias

Comment: Pues efectivamente como dice @el.trasgu, sería bien recibida. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues me ha resultado todo un reto, me ha llevamos unas horas conseguirlo, a ver si te sirve mi forma de resolverlo.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //generamos un array que recoge los números que pedimos por teclado al llamar al método
    int[] numeros = metodoPedirNumeros();
    //ceclaramos dos variable enteras con las posiciones del array recibido
    int ando = numeros[0];
    int dor = numeros[1];
    //declaramos el arrayList que se reciba del método de operaciones al que enviamos los números a multiplicar
    ArrayList<Integer> resultado = metodoMultiplicarLlevando(ando, dor);
    //por si se necesita, obtenemos el número entero del resultado
    int numero = metodoObtenerNumero(resultado);
    //llamamos al método para imprimir el resultado y enviamos el arrayList y los números a multiplicar
    metodoImprimirResultados(resultado, ando, dor);
}
//método que pide los números
public static int[] metodoPedirNumeros(){
    //instanciamos la clase escaner
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    //array que recoge los números
    int[] numeros = new int[2];

    //pedimoa los números y los almacenamos en el aray
    System.out.println("Ingrese el multiplicando");
    numeros[0] = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el multiplicador");
    numeros[1] = teclado.nextInt();
    //retornamos el array
    return numeros;
}
//método que hace la operación que recibe dos enteros y devuelve un arrayList
public static ArrayList<Integer> metodoMultiplicarLlevando(int ando, int dor){
    //convertimos a string el´número correspondiente al multiplicando
    String sAndo = Integer.toString(ando);
    //obtenemos el número de cifras del mismo
    int nAndo = sAndo.length();
    //declaramos las siguientes variables enteras
    int si = 0;
    int aux = 0;
    int multi = 0;
    int resu = 0;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    
    //declaramos un arrayList denominado números de valores enteros
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //creamos un bucle que haga tantas iteraciones como cifras tenga el multiplicando
    for (int i = nAndo; i > 0; i--){
        //ponemos a cero la variable auxiliar
        aux = 0;
        //creamos un valor char del string del número y cogemos el valor de la iteración menos 1
        char n = sAndo.charAt(i - 1);
        //convertimos en número la cifra elegida en el paso anterior
        int num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n));
        //hacemos un bucle que itere el número del multiplicador
        //una multiplicación es la suma del multiplicando tantas veces como marque el multiplicador
        for (int j = 0; j < dor; j++){
            //por cada iteración, se suma a sí mismo
            aux += num; 
        }  
        //si la variable si está en 1
        if (si == 1){
            //sumamos a la variable acumulativa, lo que llevamos de la multiplicación
            aux = aux + num1;
            //esta variable acumula el resultado, pero no la utilizamos, sirve para evaluar que los reultados coincidan
            multi += aux + num1;
            //ponemos la variable a 0
            si = 0;
        }else{
            //si no es igual a 1, sumamos el valor directamente, ya que no llevamos nada
            multi += aux;
        }            
        //si en la multiplicación anterior no tenemos decenas
        if ((aux > 0) && (aux < 10)){
            //añadimos el resultado al arrayList
            numeros.add(aux);
        }
        //si el resutlado de la pultiplicación lleva decenas
        if ((aux > 9) && (aux < 100)){
            //si no es la última iteración, o sea, si no es la última cifra del multiplicando
            if ((i - 1) > 0){
                //creamos un string del resultado de la multiplicacion
                String s2 = Integer.toString(aux);
                //obtenemos las dos cifras, decenas y unidades, del resultado
                char n1 = s2.charAt(0);
                char n2 = s2.charAt(1);
                //pasamos esos valores a números
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n1));
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n2));
                //añadimos la unidad al arrayList
                numeros.add(num2);
                //ya que llevamos las decenas, ponemos la variable en 1
                si = 1;
            }
            //si es la última cifra del multiplicando, ya no levaremos, por lo que añadimos el número completo al arrayList
            else{
                numeros.add(aux);
            }
        }            
    }
    //como hemos añadido los números por orden al arrayList, ahora lo revertimos para obtener el orden inverso
    Collections.reverse(numeros);    
    //retornamos el arrayList
    return numeros;
}
//método que imprime el resultado que recibe el arrayList, el multiplicando y el multiplicador
public static void metodoImprimirResultados(ArrayList<Integer> resultado, int ando, int dor){
    //damos el mensaje en pantalla
    System.out.print("El resultado de multiplicar " + ando + " * " + dor + " es de: ");
    //creamos un bucle que recorre el arrayList
    for (int k = 0; k < resultado.size(); k++){
        //obtenemos el valor de cada fial del arrayList y lo imprimimos
        System.out.print(resultado.get(k));
    }
    //damos una línea en blanco
    System.out.println("");
}
//metodo que extrae el número del arrayList y que recibe éste por parámetro
public static int metodoObtenerNumero(ArrayList<Integer> resultado){
    //creamos un variable string
    String aux = "";
    //bucle que recorre el arrayList
    for (int k = 0; k < resultado.size(); k++){
        //acumulamos en la variable string las filas del arrayList convertidas en string
        aux += resultado.get(k).toString();
    }
    //convertimos en número entero el string anterior
    int numero = Integer.parseInt(aux);
    //retornamos el número
    return numero;
}
```

Comment: Pues si que funciona, lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias

Comment: Las operaciones bitwise son operaciones bits a bits, puedes leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/453112/183782) aunque es en python, la lógica de como se hacen no cambia, solo cambia la sintaxis del lenguaje.

Comment: Vaya, interesante, no lo conocía, Gracias @Christian