# ¿Qué significa "x = n1 ^ n2" en python?

Tags: python, binario, números-enteros

Esto está en un ejercicio, también está en C++. La sintaxis es similar. Quiero saber si pueden ayudarme. Gracias. El operador ^ en una búsqueda lo relaciona con expresiones regulares. Pero después de anlizarla mejor me dí cuenta que era una operción O Exclusiva a nivel de bits. En realidad me apresuré en publicarla. Tendría que haberla analizado con más tiempo. Pido disculpas por haberla publicado. De todas formas le puede servir a alguien.

```
def hammingDistance(n1, n2) :

x = n1 ^ n2

setBits = 0

while (x > 0) :
    setBits += x & 1
    x >>= 1

return setBits
```

Comment: Además si pueden explicarme qué hace la función.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Es un bitwise xor o llamado "or exclusivo" pero a nivel de bits

Comment: Por cierto, que es lo que no entiendes?? Que has investigando?? Haz buscado "operador ^ en python" en Google??

Comment: La función cuenta cuántos bits son diferentes entre `n1` y `n2`. Para ello primero hace la operación XOR (`^`) entre ambos números, lo cual da como resultado 0 en los bits que son iguales y 1 en los que son diferentes. Después cuenta cuántos 1 hay en el resultado (en un bucle en el que va desplazando x hacia la derecha bit a bit, y hace AND `&` entre x y 1, por lo que mira su último bit)

Comment: yo juraba que era una operación exponencial XD

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent No, en python el exponente es `**`

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Ya la entendí. Me falto investigar más. A mí me parecía que era una XOR y un shift, pero no encontraba la respuesta, por eso la publiqué, pero después de analizarla mejor la entendí. Sólo me falto buscar mejor. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Sería excelente que agregues más detalles de lo que has investigado. Puedes leer [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/453112/183782) para que te guíes

Comment: ¡No agregues disculpas en tu pregunta! Está bien hacer preguntas, siempre y cuando se adapte a lo que se menciona en [ask] ;)

Answer (score 3):

El operador `^` es el XOR (or exclusivo).

En la operación

```
x = n1 ^ n2
```

`x` tiene un bit en 1 en una posición sólo si en la misma los bits de `n1` y `n2` difieren, según la siguiente tabla

[image: Tabla de verdad XOR]

Para comprender mejor el proceso, insertemos unos `print()`

```
def hammingDistance(n1, n2) :
    print(f"{n1:>12b}")
    print(f"{n2:>12b}")
    x = n1 ^ n2
    print(f"{x:>12b}")
    setBits = 0
    while (x > 0) :
        setBits += x & 1
        x >>= 1
    return setBits

print(hammingDistance(65,32))
```

donde usamos el formato `f"{n1:>12b}"` para obtener la representación binaria de `n1`, ajustada a 12 bits de ancho y alineada por la derecha.

```
 1000001 # n1
  100000 # n2
 1100001 # x = n1 ^ n2
3 # 3 bits en uno.
```

Como se puede apreciar, el resultado tiene tres bits en uno, y es el resultado que retorna la función.

Comment: Candid Moe. Muy buena la explicación. No está de más darte las gracias.